# How to insert values from JQuery datepicker to MySQL date datatype using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

i can't insert the values from my JQuery Datepicker to my MySQL database with Date datatype. how will i convert string to date datatype? im using Codeigniter with MVC. here's my code:

javascript

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/icons/calendar_24.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
            $("input[name='dob']").val(dateText);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

controller

```
function create()
{
    $data = array(
        'FirstName' => $this->input->post('fname'),
        'DateofBirth' => $this->input->post('dob')
    );

    $this->site_model->add_record($data);
    $this->index();
}
```

view

```
<?php echo form_open('site/create');?>
<p>
    <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="fname" />
</p>

<p>
    <input type="text" name='dob' id="datepicker" />
</p>
```

thanks guys!
i read some solution in google
and i did this:

controller:

```
function create()
{
    $date = $this->input->post('dob');

    $data = array(
        'FirstName' => $this->input->post('fname'),
        'DateofBirth' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date))
    );

    $this->site_model->add_record($data);
    $this->index();
}
```

and this solved my problem! :)

Comment: A MySQL date is a simple string with a certain format: `YYYY-MM-DD` ranging from `1000-01-01` to `9999-12-31`. Just convert the date received to this format (if needed) and insert it.

Answer (score 5):

I assume your MySQL table's dob column is of `DATE` type.
 `Date` type takes value in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd` e.g. `2012-09-21`

So to answer your question - you need to format the date from the datepicker to the above valid format. e.g. if your datepicker date is in the `dd-mm-yy` format you need to convert it to mysql date format using php's `date()` function in your controller .... (there are other methods to handle dates like datetime class too)

```
function create()
{
    $data = array(
        'FirstName' => $this->input->post('fname'),
        'DateofBirth' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $this->input->post('dob')))); 
    );

    $this->site_model->add_record($data);
    $this->index();
}
```

**NOTE when using strtotime()**

> Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at
>   the separator between the various components: if the separator is a
>   slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the
>   separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format
>   is assumed.

Comment: thx @Vamsi u studied at coventry university? I think I know one guy called Vamsi.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/icons/calendar_24.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat: 'Y-m-d'       // No need to add onselect , value selected will automatically be added to input field #datepicker       
    });

});
</script>
```

Your code is fine

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var year=new Date().getFullYear();
    var yearTo=year-18;
    var yearFrom=year-100;

    //display the years from hundred years in the past till 18 years in the past

    $( "#datePickerDOB" ).live("click",function(){      

        $( "#datePickerDOB" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            yearRange: yearFrom+":"+yearTo,
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy"
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to format the datepicker:

$('#datepicker').datepicker({dateFormat : 'yy-mm-dd'});

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should look like this:

```
{
    $date = $this->input->post('dob');

    $data = array(
        'FirstName' => $this->input->post('fname'),
        'DateofBirth' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date))
    );

    $this->site_model->add_record($data);
    $this->index();
}
```

I think this suits you better