# How to add date only in Edit Mode? TextBoxFor()

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

[image]I want to save date in database as it display while clicking edit button click in edit mode but it does not work for some dates such as `The value '17/03/2016' is not valid for EndDate.`
I want to add this to database as it display in edit mode. Using EF5.0.0.0
[image]

```
jquery
    <script type="text/javascript">
                $(function () {
                    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                        dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",
                        changeMonth: true,
                        changeYear: true,
                        yearRange: "-60:+5"
                    });
                });
            </script>

  @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StartDate,"{0:dd/M/yy}", new { @class = "datepicker"})
```

Comment: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate ...

Comment: **jquery-ui.css** **jquery-1.9.1.js** **jquery-ui.js**  scripts referd for datepicker in edit.cshtml page did u understand?

Comment: Check doc, the first thing which seems obvious is that you are using wrong format...

Comment: @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EndDate,"{0:yy-mm-dd}", new { @class = "datepicker"})                                                                              $(function () {
                $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    yearRange: "-60:+5"
                });
            });

Comment: what is this wolff?? reputation reduced !!!

Comment: what is the reason please reply??????????????????????????????????????????????????????

Comment: is it a bad question??????????????????????????????

Answer (score 1):

You execpt `"Mar."` but set `"03"`.

**Change**

```
dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",
```

**to**

```
dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
```

See
[jquery-ui Datepicker Formats](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats)

**Update for the final Resolution:**

Changing the validation code to same format as table field in mysql-database fixed the issue.
`[DataType(DataType.Date)][DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; } @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreatedDate,"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "datepicker"})`

Comment: its not working .. i m using mysql database .. is that the reason?

Comment: @Souparnika  Then you have to define database correct format for your date too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526863/how-to-insert-values-from-jquery-datepicker-to-mysql-date-datatype-using-codeign

Comment: please explain the details

Comment: in database it should be displayed as yy-mm-dd, but in create action it should be working fine but unable to edit..

Comment: Sorry please explain i cant understant

Comment: Show us please the validation function of EndDate.

Comment: [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/M/yy}")]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> EndDate { get; set; }

Comment: Did you tried it with changing this format here? `{0:dd/mm/yy}` this sould work!

Comment: Its not working is there any other option?? i want to save date to db

Comment: Is it possible so setup a jsfiddle (with the frontend part)?
You have a general Problem. Fix your problem with the validation of your endDate in Frontend. The recommend choice is to have some format in input, validation and database. If you need to store other format in Database please use php and convert it to "YYYY-MM-DD" as we can see in your topic screenshot. Thats also not confirm to "dd-mm-yyyy". Are you from Germany?

Comment: ya, Success :) i have changed the code 
 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('.datepicker').datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "yy-MM-dd",
                    changeMonth: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    yearRange: "-60:+5"
                });
            }); no i m from india :-P

Comment: [DataType(DataType.Date)][DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }     @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreatedDate,"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "datepicker"})

Comment: Nice :) I've updated the Answer. If it was the right anwers please accept it as solved to help other people.

Okay no iam from germany, i have only asked because then we can better talk (if you're also from germany) ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(function () { $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-MM-dd", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: "-60:+5" }); });</script> 




    [DataType(DataType.Date)][DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)] 
public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; } 





   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CreatedDate,"{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { @class = "datepicker"})
```

**Good Refernce for DatePickers..**
   https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

[enter link description here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/datepicker/index)

Comment: **SOLVED THE ISSUE**